# HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e') -- inner error -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use npx-create-react-app years, but now i can't build with run npm run build.

Today still is work.

I update node and npm. Clear the cahce with: npm cache clean --force

None of the projects work. neither with the old nor with the brand new.

Thank you

I not want public sensitive infromation for my pc but the essence can't load file. I'ts staring with App.css but i comment out come to next one.

```
HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
Generated code for D:\xxxx\xxx\xxx\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!D:\xxxxx\xxxxxxxzx\xxxx\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!D:\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxx\node_modules\source-map-loader\dist\cjs.js!D:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\src\App.css
```

Comment: Same problem at the exact same time, only Vue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274525/vuejs-3-hello-world-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-e

Comment: Perhaps something that related with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Webpack 5.83.1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution somebody give and i sign that was the solution. But deleted his answer cause it was solved in the meantime.

But similar error may occur later so I give that solution again...

```
 npm i webpack@5.82.0
```