# VueJS 3 - Hello World: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to setup my first vue project without success. If I run "npm run serve", I get a blank page. If I run "npm run build", I get the errors below.

The following versions are installed:

```
Node: v17.9.1
npm: 8.11.0
vue@3.3.2
@vue/cli-service@5.0.8
```

The commands I run:

```
vue create build-a-bot
cd build-a-bot
npm run build
```

The error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> build-a-bot@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build

All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.


-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors18:39:38

 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=8e132f82&lang=css

Syntax Error: HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
Generated code for C:\dev\build-a-bot\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[1]!C:\dev\build-a-bot\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\stylePostLoader.js!C:\dev\build-a-bot\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[2]!C:\dev\build-a-bot\node_modules\vue-loader\dist\index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!C:\dev\build-a-bot\src\App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=8e132f82&lang=css
 1 | __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
 2 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_noSourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__("C:\\dev\\build-a-bot\\node_modules\\css-loader\\dist\\runtime\\noSourceMaps.js");
 3 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_noSourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_noSourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
 4 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__("C:\\dev\\build-a-bot\\node_modules\\css-loader\\dist\\runtime\\api.js");
 5 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
 6 | // Imports
 7 |
 8 |
 9 | var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default()((_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_noSourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()));
10 | // Module
11 | ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, "\n#app {\n  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;\n  text-align: center;\n  color: #2c3e50;\n  margin-top: 60px;\n}\n", ""]);
12 | // Exports
13 | /* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__.d.e.f.a.u.l.t = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);
14 |


 error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=0a39cc74&scoped=true&lang=css

Syntax Error: HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
```

Comment: I'ts not connect Vue itself. React also not work. I think it with npm or node. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274398/hookwebpackerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-e-inner-err

Comment: Perhaps something that related with webpack.

Comment: I'm seeing this in my react project today. It is failing on the bootstrap css with that same css-loader. We are referencing the same version of bootstrap so maybe something weird going on with css-loader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current workaround is to downgrade webpack from 5.83.0 to 5.82.0:
npm i webpack@5.82.0

Comment: this resolved things for me as well

Comment: resolved for me. This should be the answer.