# npm run build error on typescript react app

Tags: typescript, npm, build, yarnpkg, react-typescript

I am getting this error when I am trying to build using npm run build command:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
Generated code for /Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/src/App.css
 1 | __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
 2 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__("/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[4]!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js");
 3 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
 4 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__("/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[4]!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/Users/gazakorompis/snow-typescript/frontend/github_explorer/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
 5 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
 6 | // Imports
 7 | 
 8 | 
 9 | var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default()((_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()));
10 | // Module
11 | ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, ".App {\n  /* text-align: center; */\n  margin-top: 0vh;\n  margin-left: 1vh;\n}\n\n.box {\n  border: 1px solid;\n}\n", "",{"version":3,"sources":["webpack://./src/App.css"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;EACE,wBAAwB;EACxB,eAAe;EACf,gBAAgB;AAClB;;AAEA;EACE,iBAAiB;AACnB","sourcesContent":[".App {\n  /* text-align: center; */\n  margin-top: 0vh;\n  margin-left: 1vh;\n}\n\n.box {\n  border: 1px solid;\n}\n"],"sourceRoot":""}]);
12 | // Exports
13 | ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.locals = {};
14 | /* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__.d.e.f.a.u.l.t = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);
```

Any idea, what these mean and what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e') -- inner error -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274398/hookwebpackerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-e-inner-err)